# Display a different column value in a PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following code -

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                    QUOTENAME(Name)
                  FROM JobPhases
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM    
(   
    SELECT c.Registration, p.Name, [x] = 1
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases p ON p.ID = j.PhaseId
    INNER JOIN Jobs job on job.ID = j.JobID
    INNER JOIN Cars c on job.CarID = c.ID
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   SUM(x)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) pvt'
```

Which generates this -

```
JobID | Repair & Reshape | Refit Stripped Parts | Polishing 
1000  | id               | id                   | id
1001  | id               | id                   | id
1002  | id               | id                   | id
1003  | id               | id                   | id
1004  | id               | id                   | id
```

But, I would like it to show j.EstimatedTime instead of j.ID.

The table structure -

JobDetails

```
ID - PK Auto increment
JobID - Int (Joined to Jobs table)
PhaseID - String (joined to JobPhases table)
EstimatedTime - decimal
```

JobPhases

```
ID - PK String
Name - VarChar(150)
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: But in your query you are showing `j.EstimatedTime` not `j.ID`.

Comment: Apologies, I was meant to remove this from the query. Each job detail has an estimated time associated with an individual phase. I want to show the estimated time in the required cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `[x] = 1` to `[x] = j.EstimatedTime` .